# How to remove specific element from a XML by given tag name. AXIOM

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, axiom

Folks,

I m just wondering how could I remove an xml element by given tag name from given xml using AXIOM xml process library.

so far i have successfully build document.

```
StAXOMBuilder builder = new StAXOMBuilder(stream);
OMElement documentBuilder = builder.getDocumentElement();
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OMXMLParserWrapper builder = OMXMLBuilderFactory.createOMBuilder(stream);
OMElement documentElement = builder.getDocumentElement();
Iterator it = documentElement.getChildrenWithName(new QName("http://namespace", "elementName"));
if (it.hasNext()) {
    it.next();
    it.remove();
}
```

Comment: This might be the answer to the question, but a little explanation might be for OP good to understand where his problem was and how the solution works!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the solution

```
  StAXOMBuilder builder = new StAXOMBuilder(stream);
    OMElement documentBuilder = builder.getDocumentElement();

     Iterator allChildren = documentBuilder.getChildren();
     while (allChildren.hasNext()) {
        OMElement omElement = (OMElement) allChildren.next();
        String elementName = omElement.getQName().toString();

        if ("apimPayload".equals(elementName)) {                       
        omElement.detach();
        break;
        }
     }
```